# how do I get nginx to forward HTTP POST requests via rewrite?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

My iOS app is currently accessing domain A via http POST but I would like to forward all requests to domain B.

If I use the usual `rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://mydomain/$1  permanent;` the POST data seems to get lost.

How can I pass HTTP POST data to a different domain using NginX?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using [the reverse proxy support](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) instead. An example `location` section would be:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect  http://localhost:8080/ /;
  proxy_read_timeout 60s;

  # May not need or want to set Host. Should default to the above hostname.
  proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This example will pass through all requests to this `server` block to a second server running on `localhost:8080`. This preserves `POST`'s and should also preserve other request types too if it ever becomes an issue.

The issue is that external redirects will *never* resend `POST` data. This is written into [the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (check the 3xx section). Any client that does do this is violating the spec.

> If the 301/302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

I'm fairly sure that most browsers implement this by simply forcing the redirected request to be a `GET` request. Theoretically, the spec does allow for a browser that would ask the user whether to redirect the `POST` data, but I'm unaware of any that currently do.

Comment: a little bit confused from comment. Do I generally want to set the `proxy_set_header` values? Otherwise I guess that remote address becomes the remote address of the proxy server but what I usually want is the remote address of the client, correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer that saved me! Is there a way to set up nginx so that it passes post requests correctly back to uwsgi but with sockets instead of running uwsgi in http mode?

Comment: @GregJennings A little late for a reply, but one would use the 'uwsgi_pass' directive instead of 'proxy_pass'. Just in case someone else wanders by looking...

Comment: I'm curious about `proxy_redirect  http://localhost:8080/ /`
Why the second individual `/`? What impact does that have?

Comment: @Will `proxy_redirect` takes two arguments. See the docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this in Nginx but using the `mirror` plugin not `rewrite`:

```
location "/post/uri/to/redirect/" {                                        
    mirror "/mirror";                                                       
    mirror_request_body on;                                                 
    return 200;                                                             
}                                                                           

location = "/mirror" {                                                      
    internal;                                                               
    proxy_pass "https://target_domain$request_uri";                   
    proxy_set_header Host "target_domain";                            
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;                           
    proxy_set_header X-SERVER-PORT $server_port;                            
    proxy_set_header X-SERVER-ADDR $server_addr;                            
    proxy_set_header X-REAL-IP $remote_addr;                                
}
```